# Algorithm analysis - Expected growth rates

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I have a question about clarification of my homework.

http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~gunduz/teaching/cs201/cs201_homework3.pdf

To see the handout please go to page 25 of http://www.scribd.com/nanny24/d/36657378-Data-Structures-and-Algorithm-Analysis-in-C-Weiss.

Following is what I need to do, but I didn't understand what this means. Does it mean -for algorithm 1- compare actual running time versus (n^3 + 3*(n^2) + 2*n)/6, n=array size?
I don't think so, but I couldn't infer anything else. Can you please explain me what this is?

```
2- Plot the expected growth rates obtained from the theoretical analysis (as given for each solution) by 
using the same N values that you used in obtaining your results. Compare the expected growth rates 
and the obtained results, and discuss your observations in a paragraph.
```

EDIT 2:

```
Algorithm 1:
    n           actual running time(ms)     (n^3 + 3*(n^2) + 2*n)/6 (I don't know whether the type is millisecond or not)
    100         1                       171700
    1000        851                     167167000
```

So considering this huge difference between actual running time and theoretical running time, what the instructor means may be different than theoretical time complexity function which is (n^3 + 3*(n^2) + 2*n)/6 for the algorithm 1. This is the function: http://www.diigo.com/item/image/2lxmz/m7y3?size=o

Comment: What? That result fits not bad with cubic growth. Try running it for `n = 2000` and `n = 5000` to get more data points.

Comment: Shouldn't 167167000 be more closer to 851?

Comment: You shouldn't compare the two sets by their absolute values, try to normalize the observed set by dividing all the entries by 171700, and then compare.

Comment: enobayram you're a life saver! Then, the theoretical time complexity function have no type like a milliseconds etc., their values are meaningless alone. We only care the growth rate. Right?

Comment: @noarm Yes. The theoretical time complexity is in units of "elemetary operations", how that translates to execution time depends on many factors. So you compare `time(n)/time(N_0)` to `theory(n)/theory(N_0)` for some fixed `N_0`, e.g. 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your instructor  means by "expected growth rate" the predicted running time after you plug in the value of *n* in the theoretical time complexity function.

While this usage is standard, I would still check with the instructor if I were you.

Comment: Can you please check the last addition I just wrote above? Difference between actual running time and theoretical running time is VERY huge. So considering this huge difference, what the instructor means may be different than theoretical time complexity function which is (n^3 + 3*(n^2) + 2*n)/6 for the algorithm 1. This is the function: http://www.diigo.com/item/image/2lxmz/m7y3?size=o

Comment: @noarm The scales are different. What matters is that the two functions have roughly the same shape. Suppose, you upscale your runtime by multiplying everything by 20,0000, the number start to look about the same more or less. That's the point of the experiment. To demonstrate that the actual run time has a relationship to the theoretical bounds, ignoring multiplying coefficients. Does this clear things up a bit?

Answer (score 1):

The theoretical number is probably the number of operations or comparisons or something similar.

I guess that *growth rate* means *how fast does the value grow?*. When `n` goes from `100` to `1000`, the theoretical value grows by the factor `167167000/171700 = 973.6`, compared to the real-word measured factor of 851.